# Swift scanUpToString not working as expected

Tags: swift, nsscanner

Iam having issues with `scanUpToString` method and its not working as I expect

```
let str1 = "123-456-7890"
let scanner = Scanner(string: str1)
let part1  = scanner.scanUpToString("-")
let part2  = scanner.scanUpToString("-")
let part3 = scanner.scanUpToString("-")
```

I am getting 123 for part1, but nil for part2 and part3

Is there anything more that I need to do get `part2 = 456` and `part3 = 7890` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue there is that the scanner is finding the same string "-" at the current index over and over again. If you need to use this method you would need to move the `currentIndex` one character forward after each scan:

```
let str1 = "123-456-7890"
let scanner = Scanner(string: str1)
let part1  = scanner.scanUpToString("-")  // "123"
scanner.currentIndex = str1.index(after: scanner.currentIndex)
let part2  = scanner.scanUpToString("-")  // "456"
scanner.currentIndex = str1.index(after: scanner.currentIndex)
let part3 = scanner.scanUpToString("-")  // "7890"
```

Comment: The better solution is adding `scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "-")`. Then `scanUpToString` returns correct strings.